# Prove that $f$ is injective

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\space \backslash \space \text{{0}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=\frac {x+1}x$. Prove it is injective.

I'm not sure what $\mathbb{R}\space \backslash \space \text{{0}}$ means, so a bit of explanation would be helpful. I know I have to start th

Suppose $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}\space \backslash \space \text{{0}}$ with $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ that is $\frac{x_1+1}{x_1}=\frac{x_2+1}{x_2}$

$(x_1+1)x_2=(x_2+1)x_1$

$x_1x_2+x_2=x_1x_2+x_1$

$x_1=x_2$  $\square$

I'm not sure if that's correct?

Comment: $\Bbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$ means zero is not in the domain.

Comment: Great. [few more characters]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

By the way, $\mathbb{R}\ \backslash\ \{0\}$ denotes the set of real numbers without $0$. In this case, we need $x\neq 0$ so that $f(x)$ makes sense (otherwise, what is $f(0)$?).

Answer (score 1):

\ means the difference operation between sets. $A\,\backslash\, B=\{x:x\in A\wedge x\notin B\}.$ So $\mathbb R\,\backslash \, \{0\} = (-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty).$

And your proof is correct.